# How to handle old state reducer react

Tags: reactjs, redux, reduce

I am creating a cart where the client has multiple checkboxes, I can update the cart when the checkbox is checked and update it when is unchecked, so far so good, but the problem is when the client wants to create another order, I think the reducer is bringing me the old order.

This is my reducer

```
if (action.type === ADD_ITEM_TO_CART_DETAILS) {
  return {
    ...state,
    cart: [...state.cart, action.payload]
  }
}
```

This is my action

```
export function addItemDetail(value){
 
  return {
    type   : ADD_ITEM_TO_CART_DETAILS,
    payload: value
  }
}
```

and this is the JS:

```
export default function DetailProduct() {

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { id } = useParams();
  const history = useHistory();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getDetail(id));
  }, [dispatch, id]);

  const detail = useSelector((state) => state.detail); // details of the products
  const { options, setOptions } = useContext(OrderContext);

  const BackToProducts = () => {
    if (options.salsa.length) {
      dispatch(addItemDetail(options));
    } else {
      history.push("/productos");
    }
  };

  const seeCart = () => {
    if (options.salsa.length) {
      dispatch(addItemDetail(options));
    } else {
      history.push("/carrito");
    }
  };

  const handleComments = (e) => {
    setOptions((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      Comments: e.target.value,
    }));
  };

  const handleSalsa = (e) => {
    const { name, checked } = e.target;

    if (options.salsa.length <= 2) {
      e.target.checked = false;
    } else if (checked === true) {
      setOptions((prev) => ({
        ...prev,
        salsa: [...prev.salsa, name],
        picture_url: detail.picture_url,
        id: uuidv4(),
        price: detail.price,
        title: detail.title,
      }));
    }

    if (checked === false) {
      setOptions((prev) => ({
        ...prev,
        salsa: prev.salsa.filter((p) => p !== name),
      }));
    }
  };

  const handleToppings = async (e) => {
    const { name, checked } = e.target;

    if (checked === true) {
      setOptions({ ...options, toppings: [...options.toppings, name] });
    }

    if (checked === false) {
      setOptions((prev) => ({
        ...prev,
        toppings: prev.toppings.filter((p) => p !== name),
      }));
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // useEffect to update the total amount

    const productPrice = options.price; // price of the single product
    const toppingPrice = options.priceTopping; // price of the topping

    const total = toppingPrice ? productPrice + toppingPrice : productPrice;

    setOptions((prev) => ({ ...prev, unit_price: total })); // set total amount product plus toppings
  }, [options.price, options.priceTopping, setOptions]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // useEffect to update total amount of the toppings
    const numberOfToppings = options.toppings.length;
    const totalPriceTopping = numberOfToppings !== 0 ? numberOfToppings * 119 : 0;

    setOptions((prev) => ({ ...prev, priceTopping: totalPriceTopping }));
  }, [options.toppings, setOptions]);

  return (
    <MainContainer>
      {detail.picture_url ? <PhotoProduct src={`https://hit-pasta.herokuapp.com/${detail.picture_url}`} /> : <Loading />}
      <Like
        onClick={() => {
          history.push("/productos");
        }}
      />
      <ContainerOption>
        {detail &&
          detail?.salsas?.map((p, index) => {
            return (
              <ContainerOptionChild key={index}>
                <div>
                  <Drop />
                  <LabelProductName>{p.sauce}</LabelProductName>
                </div>
                <InputOptions type="checkbox" checked={options.salsa.index} key={index} name={p.sauce} value={p.sauce} onChange={handleSalsa} />
                <Description>{p.description}</Description>
              </ContainerOptionChild>
            );
          })}
      </ContainerOption>
      <MainBoxComments>
        <h3>Comentarios</h3>
        <BoxComentario type="text" value={options.Comments} onChange={handleComments} placeholder="Agrega instrucciones o comentarios a tu orden" />
      </MainBoxComments>
      <MainBoxBtns>
        <Okay onClick={seeCart}>
          OKAY <CartIcon />
        </Okay>
        <BtnArmarOtroHit onClick={BackToProducts}>ARMAR OTRO HIT</BtnArmarOtroHit>
      </MainBoxBtns>{" "}
    </MainContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: What button in your JSX is the "create another order" button?

Comment: What is `OrderContext`?

Comment: the create another order button would be  <Okay onClick={seeCart}>
          OKAY <CartIcon />
        </Okay> or  this one  <BtnArmarOtroHit onClick={BackToProducts}>ARMAR OTRO HIT</BtnArmarOtroHit>, the client can click  on those, to create another order or see the whole order

Comment: Have you used your debugger? If not, **why not**?

Comment: and the OrderContext is this , const [options, setOptions] = useState({
    toppings: [],
    salsa: [],
    priceTopping: null,
    id: '',
    title: '',
    price: '',
    picture_url: '',
    Comments: '',
    unit_price: 0,
    quantity: 1,
  });  . is the react state where iam saving the order until the client click on the create another order, the is the moment when the action is dispatched